# JavaScript optional argument, do I need to check for undefined?

Tags: javascript

Given this:

```
function hello(name, option) {
  if (option === 'useless') {
    return '!!!!';
  } else {
    return 'Hi, ' + name;
  }
}
```

If the `option` argument is omitted, nothing bad seems to happen. Do I really need to check it?

```
if (typeof option !== 'undefined' && option === 'useless')
```

Comment: If the argument is optional, you need to set a default value for it.

Comment: No, not in this case. It's completely safe to compare `undefined` to `'useless'`

Comment: @StephenCollins that is completely incorrect

Comment: @Phil Thought so. Feel free to post an official answer.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack doesn't need an answer as you don't have a problem ;)

Comment: @Phil I suppose not! Should I delete this question then? :)

Comment: Why do you believe you need to check it?

Comment: @Shashank Not sure, that's why I asked. Maybe compatibility with older browsers or something. I thought maybe some of them would freak out for using `===` on an undefined var.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack it's only an issue if the thing you're comparing isn't a valid reference. For example, if you went `if (foo === 'whatever')`, you would get a reference error however `option` is a valid reference in the scope of your function, it just has no value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a `typeof` check.

Formal parameters are always valid [identifiers](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3.1) inside a function scope.

The parts of the spec that are of interest:

[§ 10.4.3 Entering Function Code](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3)

> 9. Perform Declaration Binding Instantiation using the function code *code* and *argumentList* as described in 10.5.

[§ 10.5 Declaration Binding Instantiation](http://es5.github.io/#x10.5) (emphasis added)

> 4. If *code* is function code, then
>       [...]
>       d. For each String *argName* in *names*, in list order do
>            i. Let *n* be the current value of *n* plus 1.
>            ii. **If *n* is greater than *argCount*, let *v* be `undefined` otherwise let *v* be the value of the *n*’th element of *args*.**
>           [...]
>            v. Call *env*’s SetMutableBinding concrete method passing *argName*, *v*, and *strict* as the arguments.

This means, for a `function f(arg) {}` called with insufficient arguments (e.g. `f()`), the `arg` binding will be initialized to `undefined` inside its [execution context](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3) (a.k.a. scope).